# Can't use if statement to check for POST data.

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am using ajax call to grab some data from my mysql database. This is my ajax call:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "fetch.php",
    data: id,
    success: function(msg) {
        var record = JSON.parse(msg);
        $("#name").val(record.name);
        $("#description").val(record.description);
        switch(record.category) {
            case ("Residential"):
                $("#category").val("residential");
                break;
            case ("Modernisation & Domestic Extensions"):
                $("#category").val("modernisation");
                break;
            case ("Feasibility Layouts"):
                $("#category").val("feasibility");
                break;
            case ("Master Planning"):
                $("category").val("master");
                break;
            default:
                $("category").val("");
        };
        switch(record.featured) {
            case ("y"):
                $("#featured").val("y");
                break;
            default:
                $("featured").val("n");
        };
    }
})
```

and this is my php file:

```
       <?php 
       $dbc = mysqli_connect('XX','XX','XX','XX');

       $id = $_POST['id'];

       if($dbc) {
          $row = fetchDataFromRecordWithId($dbc,$id);
       }
       else {
          echo 'Database error';
       }

       function fetchDataFromRecordWithId($dbc,$id) {
          $q = "SELECT * FROM Projects WHERE id = ".$id;
          $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

          $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
          mysqli_close($dbc);
          return $row;
       }

       echo json_encode($row);
       ?>
```

Everything work flawless but soon when I try to add if statement in my php file to check if there is any POST data than my ajax call is not getting any response. I tried different methods :

```
   <?php if(isset($_POST)) { .. my whole php code here .. } ?>

   <?php if(!empty($_POST)) { ..my whole php code here .. } ?>

   <?php if($_POST) { .. my whole php code here .. } ?>

   <?php if($_POST['id']) { .. my whole php code here .. } ?>
```

but nothing work! Ajax call is not getting json data back when I will use any of these if statements listed above.

I could not check for POST data and leave it like it is but I want to do is in proper way.

It seems like if statement is not executed (but POST data must be there as I am able to fetch `$_POST['id']` value when if statement not used).

I also tried to put `echo json_encode($row)` outside if statement but it didn't help either. Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: can you show us the code that actually fails?

Comment: can u told us ERROR.. which are you facing..

Comment: Please edit your question Title .. its too long..

Comment: The code above works properly without using any of the if statements listed above. Problem is when I am trying to check if there is $_POST data than my ajax call is not getting json data message back.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "fetch.php",
  data: id,
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/:

> data: [...] Object must be Key/Value pairs.

So make that line

```
  data: { id : id },
```

instead, then it should work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I didn't past the whole code and my id variable is defined earlier on as  var id = "id="+pathid;  so I suppose I have key and value in my POST request.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
   die("Invalid request method: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
}

if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
   ... db code here ...
}
```

also note that your are WIDE open for [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: Agree on the SQL injections.

Comment: I tried if (isset($_POST['id'])) { .. } and still have the same problem, ajax call is not getting json data back on success.

Comment: btw. What is the main issue with my code which allows for injection attacks? I will go through the links you posted but if it is possible to answer quickly what should I changed to make it safer I will appreciate your respond. I see that I should put my connection to separate file, will be that enough?

Comment: no. where you make your DB has NOTHING to do with injection problems. just go to the site I linked and read the cartoon there. the rest of site has per-language details on how to avoid/mitigate the problems.

Answer (score 0):

you try follow testings on your code

1. check whether you have have the right request page for php .
2. see in google chromes right click inspect element then console tab any errors are showing
3. in your suceess:function(msg) add $("body").append(msg)
4. add function before success:function(result) {}

   error:function(xhr,err){
   alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status);
   alert("responseText: "+xhr.responseText);
    }